Is it possible to have a closed(-ish) natural motion circumnavigation around an eccentric target? If so, what parameters define the NMC orbit?
Natural motion circumnavigation (NMC) is when a chaser spacecraft is set in an orbit similar to a target spacecraft's such that the chaser naturally circumnavigates the target spacecraft as a result of solely their orbital dynamics. The chaser spacecraft's motion can be described in coordinates relative to the target, such as in a RIC frame, using, for example, the Clohessy-Wiltshire equations, which assumes the target is in a circular orbit and assumes the relative difference in position between the two satellites is much smaller than the target's orbital radius.
As I understand it, using those equations, and assuming an NMC orbit that is centered on the target, the chaser's location relative to the target can be described as:
$R(t) = \frac{\alpha}{2}\cos(nt + \phi)$
$I(t) = -\alpha\sin(nt+\phi)$
$C(t) = \beta\cos(nt-\psi)$,
where $\alpha$ is the amplitude of the relative orbit in the orbital plane (which actually is shaped like an ellipse), $\beta$ is the amplitude of the relative orbit out of the orbital plane of the target, $\phi$ and $\psi$ are phasing parameters, $t$ is time, and $n$ is the mean motion of the orbits.
So from these equations, given a target orbit (and thus $n$), all one needs to do is select values for $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\phi$, and $\psi$ and you can solve for the initial RIC position you need to achieve to be on an NMC orbit centered on the target. You can even set time to 0 to simplify the calculation. I don't recall the velocity equations off-hand, but I remember seeing they had a simple, closed form solution for the same parameters, so given values for $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\phi$, and $\psi$ you can solve for the orbital state needed to achieve an NMC around a target given those parameters.

Now I'm interested in the same thing, but for targets on eccentric orbits. I read this paper by Yamanaka & Ankersen (which unfortunately I don't think I have rights to just post here), who derive equations of motion for the chaser relative orbit for a target of arbitrary eccentricity up to 1, which reduces to the Clohessy-Wiltshire equations in the zero-eccentricity case. It's been a while since I've worked with differential equations, though, and I'm not used to working with state transition matrices, so I'm not seeing how to get from their general solution of relative position/velocity over time to specifically what are the minimum parameters needed to entirely specify an NMC orbit centered on (if that's possible for an eccentric case) a target, and then how to calculate the relative position/velocity that will put the chaser on that orbit.
Is there a different paper/blog/slideshow somewhere that spells those specific parameters and equations for me? If not, how should I approach the equations in the paper to get them into a form like that?
